# Find runtime of Multiple Recurrences using Iterative Substitution

Tags: algorithm, runtime, iteration, substitution

I am trying to find the runtime of the following recurrence using iterative substitution:

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/3) + n
```

The issue is that there are two `T(n/x)` terms and finding general form for this case has proven to be quite challenging. 
Is there a general guideline one should follow using iterative substitution for cases like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This recurrence is from the class of [Akra–Bazzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method#The_formula) recurrences . Following the formula the solution is:

[image]
[image]

Alternatively, suppose that `T(1) = c0` then you can prove that `T(n) <= max(6,c0)*n` by induction.

You can also use the substitution rule. Here's how:

```
T(n) = T(n/2)+T(n/3) + n = 
= n+(n/2+n/3)+T(n/(2*2))+T(n/(2*3))+T(n/(3*2))+T(n/(3*3))
= n+(n/2+n/3)+(n/(2*2)+n/(2*3)+n/(3*2)+n/(3*3))
             +T(n/(2*2*2))+T(n/(2*2*3))
             +T(n/(2*3*2))+T(n/(2*3*3))
             +T(n/(3*2*2))+T(n/(3*2*3))
             +T(n/(3*3*2))+T(n/(3*3*3))=
...
= n * (1 + 5/6 + (5/6)^2 + (5/6)^3 + (5/6)^4 + ...)
= 6 * n (assuming n = 2^k3^k. you get < 6*n otherwise)
```

Comment: Is it possible to solve this with iterative substitution though?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing formal here, but

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n // O(nlog(n))
```

So your recurrence might still be O(nlog(n))?

Also what is the base case?